# How to create a SQLite databse to store input that user key in, not related to listview?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have no idea how to create a database to store my user information.
I have a rough idea on how to create a database but that is only for item in the listview. I want to store my user information so that i can edit the information anytime. But whenever i key in the value and manage to get my calories, once i exit the app i have to re-enter all the information again.

**This is my layout file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    tools:context=".Calculator"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Age"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Age"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/food"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Height"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Height"
        android:text="Weight: (kg)"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Height"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/height"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/age"
        android:text="Height: (cm)"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Age"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Age:"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Height"
        android:layout_below="@+id/food"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Height" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Gender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gender: "
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Name" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
        android:orientation ="vertical">

        <RadioButton

            android:id="@+id/Male"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Gender"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Gender"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Female"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Female"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Male"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Gender"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:text="Female" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/food"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/food"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_light"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/height"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/height"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/age"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:textColor="?attr/actionMenuTextColor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calc" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is my java code:**

```
public class Calculator extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText weight, height, age, name;
double calculate, result;
RadioButton radioGender;
int selectedId;
private Button button;
TextView calresult;
private Cursor model = null;
private CalculatorHelper helper2 = null;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calories_calculator);



    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
            height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
            age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
            name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.food);
            helper2 = new CalculatorHelper(Calculator.this);
            model = helper2.getAll();



            int Gender;

            RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            RadioButton male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Male);
            RadioButton female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Female);

            selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            radioGender = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            if (male.isChecked()) {
                Gender = 1;
            } else {
                Gender = 2;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString())) {
                name.setError("Please enter your name");
                Toast.makeText(Calculator.this, "Please enter your name",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }


            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(weight.getText().toString())) {
                weight.setError("Please enter your weight");
                return;
            }


            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(height.getText().toString())) {
                height.setError("Please enter your height");
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(age.getText().toString())) {
                age.setError("Please enter your age");
                return;
            }
            String namevr = name.getText().toString();
            double weightvr = Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
            double heightvr = Double.parseDouble(height.getText().toString());
            int agevr = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(Calculator.this, DataCalculator.class);
            intent.putExtra("NAME", namevr);
            result = calculate + 0;
            intent.putExtra("RESULT", result);
            //a.putString("name", String.valueOf(namevr));

            if ((weightvr <= 30) || (weightvr >= 200)) {
                Toast.makeText(Calculator.this, "Please enter a valid weight",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            } else if ((heightvr <= 120) || (heightvr >= 220)) {
                Toast.makeText(Calculator.this, "Please enter a valid height",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } else if ((agevr <= 0) || (agevr >= 120)) {
                Toast.makeText(Calculator.this, "Please enter a valid age",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } else {

                if (selectedId == R.id.Male) {
                    calculate = (((weightvr * 10) + (heightvr * 6.25)) - (5 * agevr)) + 5;

                } else {
                    calculate = (((weightvr * 10) + (heightvr * 6.25)) - (5 * agevr)) - 161;
                }

            }

            intent.putExtra("RESULT", String.valueOf(calculate));

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: check this tutorial  https://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that CalculatorHelper will be your database helper.

Step 1 - Create/Amend CallculatorHelper to

- extend the SQLiteOpenHelper class

i.e. use `public class CalculatorHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { ...... }`

The class extending the SQLiteOpenHelper requires a minimum of 3 entities

1. a constructor that calls the super constructor of the SQLiteOpenHelper class.

   - this call requires 4 values,
   - 1) a valid Context,
   - 2) the name of the database (this will be the name of the file),
   - 3) a CursorFactory (null will be used as one isn't needed),
   - 4) an int version number (1 being the first).
2. An override for the public **onCreate** method that has 1 parameter passed to it

   - the SQLiteDatabase object that has been created. The method returns nothing and is therefore defined using void.
3. An override for the public **onUpgrade** method that has 3 parameters passed to it

   - the SQliteDatabase object
   - the version number that is stored in the database (the old version)
   - the version number that has been passed to the constructor of the SQLiteOpenHelper super constructor (the new version).
4. Is typically where you create the tables for the database.
5. Is where you would code alterations to the schema when the version is increased.

However the above is useless unless the database has a table or more. So really the design of the database should be first.

Step 2 (should really be 1) **Design**

It appears that you want to save the Name/Food, Weight, Height, Age and gender.

So without going into normalisation issues etc the assumption is that you want to store the above perhaps on a button click.

As such you want a table that has columns for the Name/Food, Weight, Height, Age and gender.

SQLite is very flexible when it comes to the types of data but has 5 types of columns TEXT, INTEGER, REAL, NUMERIC and BLOB [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Name/Food will be a string so TEXT.
Weight and Height and Age are INTEGER. 
There is no boolean type so Gender will be stored as INTEGER.

As such you want a table with the above

The table needs a name. So perhaps **person_data** will do. SQLite uses it's implementation of SQL (Structured Query Language) and to create a table if uses CREATE TABLE [SQL As Understood By SQLite - CREATE TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

So perhaps `CREATE TABLE person_data (_name TEXT, _weight INTEGER, _height INTEGER, _age INTEGER, _gender INTEGER)` will suffice.
- **_** being used before any word so as to ensure that an invalid column name is avoided.

It is strongly suggest that all names of entities table names, column names etc use a single source for the name. This significantly reduces the chance for typing errors. As such it is suggested that these are added as public static final variables to the database helper class.

To create the table when the database has been created the SQLiteDatabase **execSQL** method can be used. This is one way to run SQL that does not return a result (if the table creation fails then an exception will result as it's an unrecoverable situation).

The table is useless unless data can be inserted and typically you want to be able to update data and perhaps delete data. To be able to do so matters are generally simplified if a row (an entry in the table) can be easily uniquely identified. As such a special column will be added that allows a row to be uniquely identified, actually without specifying otherwise this column exists so really we are creating an alias for that underlying column called the **rowid**. The special SQL for creating such a column is to use `column_name_to_be_the_alias INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. With android there are some instances where the column name has to be a specific name (Cursor Adapters) as such there is a constant called BaseColumns._ID. This will be used for the column name.

With the Android SDK there are what are called convenience methods (they write the SQL given a few paramaters on your behalf, they also provide protection against SQL injection). The SQLiteDatabase **insert**, **update** and **query** methods will be utilised.

Apply all the above then **CalculatorHelper.java** could be :-

```
public class CalculatorHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "calculator.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String PERSONDATA_TABLENAME = "person_data";
    public static final String COL_PERSONDATA_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_PERSONDATA_NAME = "_name";
    public static final String COL_PERSONDATA_WEIGHT = "_weight";
    public static final String COL_PERSONDATA_HEIGHT = "_height";
    public static final String COL_PERSONDATA_AGE = "_age";
    public static final String COL_PERSONDATA_GENDER = "_gender";

    public static final String PERSONDATA_TABLESQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            PERSONDATA_TABLENAME + "(" +
            COL_PERSONDATA_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            COL_PERSONDATA_NAME + " TEXT," +
            COL_PERSONDATA_WEIGHT + " INTEGER," +
            COL_PERSONDATA_HEIGHT + " INTEGER, " +
            COL_PERSONDATA_AGE + " INTEGER, " +
            COL_PERSONDATA_GENDER + " INTEGER " +
            ")";

    public CalculatorHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(PERSONDATA_TABLESQL); //<< when the database is created create the table

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public long insertPersonData(String name, int weight, int heigh, int age, boolean gender) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); //<< gets the SQLiteDatabase object for this instance
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); //<< ContentValues are key (column name) value 
        cv.put(COL_PERSONDATA_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COL_PERSONDATA_WEIGHT,weight);
        cv.put(COL_PERSONDATA_HEIGHT,heigh);
        cv.put(COL_PERSONDATA_AGE,age);
        cv.put(COL_PERSONDATA_GENDER,gender); 
        //<< NOTE id isn't specified SQLite will generate an id (the value returned)
        return db.insert(PERSONDATA_TABLENAME,null,cv);
        // Writes and executes the SQL () assuming insertPersonData:-
        // INSERT INTO person_data (_name,_weight,_height,_age,_gender) VALUES('Fred',75,160,21,0)
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param id        The id of the row to be updated
     * @param newName   The new name to apply ("" or null if not to change)
     * @param newWeight The new weight to apply (null or less than 1 to not change)
     * @param newHeight as per weight for height
     * @param newAge    as per weight for age
     * @param newGender true or false or null if to not be changed
     * @return          the number of rows update (should be 1 or 0, o if nothing changed)
     */
    public int updatePersonData(long id, String newName, Integer newWeight, Integer newHeight, Integer newAge, Boolean newGender) {
        int rv = 0;
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        if (newName != null && newName.length() > 0 ) {
            cv.put(COL_PERSONDATA_NAME,newName);
        }
        if (newWeight != null && newWeight > 0) {
            cv.put(COL_PERSONDATA_WEIGHT,newWeight);
        }
        if (newHeight != null && newHeight > 0) {
            cv.put(COL_PERSONDATA_HEIGHT,newHeight);
        }
        if (newAge != null && newAge > 0) {
            cv.put(COL_PERSONDATA_AGE,newAge);
        }
        if (newGender != null) {
            cv.put(COL_PERSONDATA_GENDER,newGender);
        }
        if (cv.size() > 0) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            rv = db.update(PERSONDATA_TABLENAME,cv,COL_PERSONDATA_ID + "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        }
        return rv;
    }

    public int deletePersonData(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(PERSONDATA_TABLENAME,COL_PERSONDATA_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }

    /**
     * Returns ALL persondata as a Cursor object
     * @return 
     */
    public Cursor getAllPersonDataRows() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(
                PERSONDATA_TABLENAME,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
    }

    public Cursor getPersonByID(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(
                PERSONDATA_TABLENAME,
                null,
                COL_PERSONDATA_ID+"=?",
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
    }
}
```

You could then add a button e.g. with an id of save to the layout  and then use :-

```
    setContentView(R.layout.calories_calculator); //<<<<<<<<<< existing code
    helper2 = new CalculatorHelper(this);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc); //<<<<<<<<<< existing code
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Boolean gender = true;
            if (((RadioButton)Calculator.this.findViewById(R.id.Male)).isChecked()) {
                gender = false;
            }
            long newid = helper2.insertPersonData(
                    (((EditText)Calculator.this.findViewById(R.id.food)).getText().toString()),
                    Integer.parseInt(((EditText)Calculator.this.findViewById(R.id.weight)).getText().toString()),
                    Integer.parseInt(((EditText)Calculator.this.findViewById(R.id.height)).getText().toString()),
                    Integer.parseInt(((EditText)Calculator.this.findViewById(R.id.age)).getText().toString()),
                    gender
            );
            String msg = "Not Inserted into the database.";
            if (newid > 0) {
                msg = "Successfully Inserted into the database.";
            }
            Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Example getting data and traversing a Cursor
            Cursor csr = helper2.getAllPersonDataRows();
            while (csr.moveToNext()) {
                String gendertype = "M";
                if (csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(CalculatorHelper.COL_PERSONDATA_GENDER)) > 0) {
                    gendertype = "F";
                }
                Log.d("PERSONDATA",
                        "Name is " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(CalculatorHelper.COL_PERSONDATA_NAME)) +
                                "\nWeight is " + String.valueOf(
                                        csr.getInt(
                                                csr.getColumnIndex(CalculatorHelper.COL_PERSONDATA_WEIGHT)
                                        )
                        ) + "kg" +
                                "\nHeight is " + String.valueOf(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(CalculatorHelper.COL_PERSONDATA_HEIGHT))) + " cm" +
                                "\nAge is " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(CalculatorHelper.COL_PERSONDATA_AGE)) + " years" +
                                "\nGender is " + gendertype +
                                "\nUnique Row Identifier is " + String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(CalculatorHelper.COL_PERSONDATA_ID)))
                );
            }
            csr.close(); //<< IMPORTANT to close Cursors when done with them
        }
    });
    //........... rest of your code here ...........
```

When you click the **SAVE** button you have added, then

- The data will be saved to the database.
- A Toast will say that it has been added to the database.
- The log will contain some output about the rows in the database.

E.g. after adding 2 rows then the log might contain :-

```
07-14 10:15:28.462 25100-25100/s.e.so57021686calculator D/PERSONDATA: Name is Fred
    Weight is 75kg
    Height is 166 cm
    Age is 61 years
    Gender is M
    Unique Row Identifier is 1
07-14 10:15:28.462 25100-25100/s.e.so57021686calculator D/PERSONDATA: Name is Mary
    Weight is 68kg
    Height is 34 cm
    Age is 159 years
    Gender is F
    Unique Row Identifier is 2
```

Showing that data has been saved (i.e. the data from Fred was previously saved). If the App is restarted and another row is added then 3 would be displayed and so on.

Comment: Ok the log display the data that has been saved, but now i have a menu button which is EditProfile, when i click on it it will return to my user page but a blank user page where i have to re-enter the user particulars again

Comment: @ZengXi Use an Intent to return the **_id** value for the user (as per newid). Then with the **_id** you can get the values by using the **getPersonByID** method.

Comment: This is my menu, the profile is the one that will edit the user information
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case (R.id.profile):
                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(DataCalculator.this,Calculator.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }